# Variable range base on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure if I did the code correctly but it is there.

My quandary is this line `ws.Range("B" & J, Range("K" & J)).copy`.  It is giving me a Run-time error 1004 Method range of object worksheet failed.

What I am trying to do is copy/paste any row b:k if column "P" indicated "recorded".

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
Sub Clear_Recorded()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Integer 'Data Tab
Dim count As Integer

Set ws = Sheet1 'Data
Set ws1 = Sheet11 'Archive
count = 0

lRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For J = 2 To lRow

    If ws.Range("P" & J).Value = "Recorded" Then
        count = count + 1
        ws.Range("B" & J, Range("K" & J)).copy
        ws1.Range("A" & count).PasteSpecial
    End If

Next J
```

Comment: `ws.Range("B" & J & ":K" & J)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get rid of the second "Range" and the extra parenthesis.  Hope this helps!

```
ws.Range("B" & J, "K" & J).Copy
```

Edit: Spelling

Comment: Thank you.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a worksheet object without referencing any kind of sheet.

How to fix this issue:

```
set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
```

Also you should rather use this:

```
 if ws.Range("P2").Offset(J-1) = "Recorded" then
'Rest of code goes here
```

`.Offset` has the parameters `RowOffset` ,`ColumnOffset`
This should solve your problem.

Comment: that is not true.  `Set ws = Sheet1` is using the codename for the sheet and is arguably a better method than what you propose as it does not matter the name of the sheet, which can be changed by the user.  The codename can only be changed through code or the vbe and is created when the sheet is added.